Cookies Data is not accessible
I deployed a web application on Vercel  and render and implemented Google login functionality in it. I set the access token, refresh token, and other information in cookies. However, when I try to access this data i, it shows empty. It works fine on my local machine, but after production. Cookies is also set in my browser , but when  try   to get  access then  it not access it show empty.
see the image  for batter understating
cookies data set in browser

 it show empty when i console cookies

 here in code  i am consoling

 set  data in cookies in  backend 

i am expecting  in console i get  all data which i am set in cookies so that i can check  user is  login or not
